# gtk3 frame label location 3.18 versus 3.22

Tags: python-3.x, gtk3

I get different visual results running the same code on Gtk 3.18 vs Gtk 3.22.  The code below creates a Gtk.Frame and shows it in a window.  The Gtk Frame has a red border, and the frame label text says "Frame Label Text".

[Here is a screen shot of Gtk 3.18](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eY2SQ.png).  The frame label text appears ABOVE the red frame border.

[Here is a screen shot of Gtk 3.22](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVhCf.png).  The frame label text appears BELOW the red frame border.

My question, how can I get Gtk 3.22 to behave like Gtk 3.18 and show the label above the border of the frame?

Here is the code:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk # pylint: disable=wrong-import-position

class GtkWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self)

    def showme(self):
        window = Gtk.Window()
        gtk_version = "Gtk Version major:{0}, minor:{1}, micro: {2}".format(Gtk.MAJOR_VERSION, Gtk.MINOR_VERSION, Gtk.MICRO_VERSION)
        window.set_title(gtk_version)
        window.set_default_size(480, 320)
        window.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
        frame = Gtk.Frame.new("Frame Label Text")
        frame.set_label_align(0.0, 1.0)
        inner_label = Gtk.Label("I am a child label")
        frame.add(inner_label)
        window.add(frame)

        css = b'''
            .frame {
            border-radius : 10px;
            border: 5px solid red;
            background-color: gray;
            color : white;
            }
            .label {
                border-radius : 5px;
                border: 2px solid yellow;
                background-color : gray;
                color: white;
            }
        '''
        css_provider = Gtk.CssProvider()
        css_provider.load_from_data(css)
        frame_style_context = frame.get_style_context()
        frame_style_context.add_class("frame")
        frame_style_context.add_provider(css_provider, Gtk.STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_USER)
        label_style_context = frame.get_label_widget().get_style_context()
        label_style_context.add_class("label")
        label_style_context.add_provider(css_provider, Gtk.STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_USER)
        window.show_all()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    win = GtkWindow()
    win.showme()
    Gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 0):

GtkCss [changed a lot](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/ch32s10.html) in 3.20.

I'm not an expert in GtkCss, but it looks like in 3.22 `.frame` class refers to the whole widget (see Css Nodes section [here](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.22/GtkFrame.html#GtkFrame.description)). To make things work you should tune your css rules and detect exact Gtk version.

Compare the following css rules:

3.14 (I don't have 3.18, but it looks the same)

```css
.frame {
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 5px solid red;
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
}

.label {
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px solid yellow;
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
}

.frame.border {
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px solid green;
  background-color: cyan;
  color: magenta;
}
```

3.22

```css
.frame {
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 5px solid red;
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
}

.frame>border {
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px solid green;
  background-color: cyan;
  color: magenta;
}

.frame>label {
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px solid yellow;
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
}
```

They look [this way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXOSc.jpg). Please also note that I've set frame label vertical alignment to 0.5 to make it easily distinguishable

Comment: Thanks for replying Alexander Dmitriev.  You are right, the css system changed drastically (and incompatilby) between Gtk 3.18 and 3.22.  I did some experimentation and I'm going to post the results below.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR, Gtk 3.18 and Gtk 3.22 are incompatible and yield very different visual results from the same code.  I was able to get the effect I was looking for on Gtk 3.22 by adjusting the css, but this completely broke the display in Gtk 3.18.

[Here is the results on Gtk 3.22](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGVAh.png)

[Here is the results on Gtk 3.18](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hcfC.png)

Below is the code, based on Alexander Dmitriev's code, that works on Gtk 3.22.  It is primarily css changes.

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk # pylint: disable=wrong-import-position

class GtkWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self)

    def showme(self):
        window = Gtk.Window()
        gtk_version = "Gtk Version major:{0}, minor:{1}, micro: {2}".format(Gtk.MAJOR_VERSION, Gtk.MINOR_VERSION, Gtk.MICRO_VERSION)
        window.set_title(gtk_version)
        window.set_default_size(480, 320)
        window.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
        frame = Gtk.Frame.new("Frame Label Text")
        frame.set_label_align(0.0, 1.0)
        inner_label = Gtk.Label("I am a child label")
        frame.add(inner_label)
        window.add(frame)

        css = b'''
        .frame {
        border-radius: 0px;
        border: none;
        background-color: white;
        color: white;
        }

        .frame>border {
        border-radius: 10px;
        border: 5px solid red;
        background-color: gray;
        color: white;
        }

        .frame>label {
        border-radius: 5px;
        border: 2px solid yellow;
        background-color: gray;
        color: white;
        }'''

        css_provider = Gtk.CssProvider()
        css_provider.load_from_data(css)
        frame_style_context = frame.get_style_context()
        frame_style_context.add_class("frame")
        frame_style_context.add_provider(css_provider, Gtk.STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_USER)
        label_style_context = frame.get_label_widget().get_style_context()
        #label_style_context.add_class("label")
        label_style_context.add_provider(css_provider, Gtk.STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_USER)
        window.show_all()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    win = GtkWindow()
    win.showme()
    Gtk.main()
```

As a bit of background, Gtk 3.18.9 is what ships with Ubuntu 16.04.  Gtk 3.22.11 is what ships with Raspbian Stretch on a Raspberry Pi.  So I guess I'll upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04, which ships with Gtk 3.22.  And then I guess I'll have to rewrite my presentation layer.

Comment: You can manually check Gtk version and use 2 sets of CSS rules